# How could I repair this drywall crack that is next to the tub so that this won’t happen again?

Tags: drywall, repair, crack, drywall-mud

I want to repair this so it doesn’t happen again, how would I do that?

[image: this is the crack]

Comment: I see peeling paint. I see green board(?). I see a small gap between tub surround & the wall that needs to be caulked (with silicone tub & tile caulk).I see a paint repair (that has at least 100 how-to questions and answers on this site alone). I even see a gap in the tub surround that needs to be recaulked. I don't see a "drywall crack". Care to be more specific about which particular issue you need help with? A hand-drawn red circle will earn you kudos. ;)

Comment: That about sums up my concerns ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove that whole strip of drywall,
- replace with cementboard/tile backer,
- thinset an accent tile strip (with bullnose to the blue wall) for the area that's getting wet from the
  tub,
- caulk,
- move on with life.

Or keep messing around with paint and mud in an area that's getting wet, repeatedly, be stuck. You could try upgrading the shower curtain, or adding corner **shower splash guards** to block more water, but that's dubious.